# Repetir una estructura de manera dinámica las veces que se necesite

Tags: jquery

Buenas, ¿como podría hacer para añadir un `div` y todo su contenido de nuevo?

Es decir, como podeis ver en el código, tengo un `div` que se llama *modalFila3* y me gustaría que el usuario al clicar sobre el botón *Añadir ejercicio* pudiera añadir una línea más al formulario que está rellenando. Esa línea es equivalente al `div` con nombre *ModalFila3*.

En la parte de `html` he creado la parte que siempre será igual para todos los usuarios del formulario, pero este ha de poder ampliarse según considere en cada momento el usuario.

Como esto cambiará cada vez, no puedo tenerlo oculto e ir haciéndolo aparecer como con la estructura inicial, si no que debo crearlo mediante `js` (`JQuery` en mi caso). Mi duda es esa, como hago para "copiar" el `div` que me interesa y pegarlo tantas veces sea necesario.

Salud.

```js
$('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {
  //Hacemos aparecer el formulario del WOD
  $('#Modal-Formulario').css('display', 'flex');

  // "+ Ejercicio" Añade otra línea de ejercicio
  $('#Anyadir-Ejercicio').click(function() {
    ('#Modal-Formulario').append(
      //AQUÍ DEBERÍA INSERTAR OTRA MODALFILA3
    );
  });
});
```

```css
/****** Btn insertar nuevo WOD ******/

#Anyadir-Rutina-Box {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#Anyadir-Rutina-btn {
  background-color: #a3c6c4;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/***** Formulario insertar nuevo WOD *****/

#Modal-Formulario {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #354649;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ModalFila {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

#ModalFila3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#ModalFila4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Inputs-Modal {
  padding: 3px;
}

.TextoFormulario {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.BtnFormulario {
  background-color: #a3c6c4;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.BtnFormulario:hover {
  outline: 1px solid;
  outline-color: #FFF;
}

#Titulo1 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#Titulo3 {
  width: 40%;
}

#Guardar-modal-btn {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


/***** Tabla donde se muestran los WODs *****/

#Tabla-Rutinas {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <h1> Diario de entreno</h1>

  <!-- Tabla donde se muestran los WODs -->
  <table id="Tabla-Rutinas">
  </table>

  <!-- Formulario para insertar nuevo WOD -->
  <div id="Modal-Formulario">
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila1">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Título">
    </div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila2">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Objetivo">
    </div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila3">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Ejercicio">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Herramienta">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Rondas">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Repeticiones">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Peso propuesto">
      <input type="text" class="Inputs-Modal TextoFormulario" placeholder="Peso final">
    </div>
    <div class="ModalFila" id="ModalFila4">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" value="Guardar">
      <input type="Button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" value="Cancelar">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" value="+ Objetivo">
      <input type="button" class="Inputs-Modal BtnFormulario" id="Anyadir-Ejercicio" value="+ Ejercicio">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Btn para hacer aparecer formulario "nuevo WOD" -->
  <div id="Anyadir-Rutina-Box">
    <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Puedes seleccionar el div ya sea por id o nombre y luego lo clonas `var divClon = $('#ModalFila3').clone()`

Comment: @Yikarus No conocía la existencia de este método. Ahora lo investigo ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO** gracias al consejo de @Yikarus

```
$('#Anyadir-Ejercicio').click(function(){
        // Clono la fila 3.
        var clonModalFila3 = $('#ModalFila3').clone();
        $('#ModalFila3').after(clonModalFila3);
    });
```

Comment: En estos casos habría sido mejor sugerir a @Yikarus que escribiera una respuesta la cual habrías marcado como solución. Es una forma de valorar el esfuerzo que otros hacen por ayudarte, en vez de escribir una auto-respuesta, la cual sería legítima en el caso de haber encontrado la solución por ti mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Para clonar *(copiar)* un Elemento HTML, en Vanilla JavaScript se proporciona el método [Node.cloneNode(deep)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Para agregar un Elemento HTML después de un Elemento HTML, en Vanilla JavaScript se proporciona el método [Element.insertAdjacentElement(pos, text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement).

> Para tu caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
document.querySelector('#Anyadir-Ejercicio').onclick = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('#ModalFila3');
  el.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', el.cloneNode(true));
}
```